# Hazelcast partition's owner and replicas? What keys contained in this partition?

Tags: key, hazelcast, partition

I have a Hazelcast Map.

I can get partitionService easily.

> PartitionService partitionService = Hazelcast.getPartitionService();
>
> Partition partition = partitionService.getPartition(key);
>
> Member ownerMember = partition.getOwner();

Questions:

1) Given a partition I can get what node is the owner of this partition. Is there any API to figure out which nodes are the backup nodes of the partition?

2) As you know value in the map is assigned to a partition based on its key.  Its very easy to determine what partition a key belongs to.  What I want to know is: given a partition what keys does it contain. In other way, if I lose some partition, can I figure out what keys I have lost?

Answer (score 2):

1) I think the only way is through the InternalPartitionService.

public InternalPartitionImpl getPartition(int partitionId)

In the InternalPartitionImpl you can access the backups as well.

2) That is a difficult one. Normally there are backups (depending on the configuration), so with that in place, the chance for data-loss should be small. Only when you loose primary and backups at the same time, you can get a data-loss.